# PHP ftp_put, local file?

Tags: php, file

If i have a local file, for example, c:/test.txt, what path do i need to type in the ftp_put function to make it work (string $local_file)? When i try with "c:/test.txt" i get an error.

Thanks

Comment: What error exactly ? Can you show us the relevant part of your code ?

Comment: Are you running ftp_put on a local server? wamp, xampp, etc? If the file calling ftp_put is on a remote server, the file you're 'putting' would have to be local to that server

Comment: Its on a remote server. Am i using wrong php function? I want to upload a local file to a remote ftp. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Its on a remote server. Am i using wrong php function? I want to upload a local file to a remote ftp ...
```

Yes, you're using the wrong function.. Remember - PHP executes on the *SERVER*, not in your browser and not on your local machine. Any FTP connection you establish in the PHP script will be relative to the server.

e.g. If you've got something like this:

```
(your machine)   ---->   (your website)   ----> (other machine you ftp to)
```

The FTP connection will be between "your website" and "other machine you ftp to". Any "local" path you specify for a file will be local to "your website", not "your machine".

You'd first have to upload the file via regular HTTP file sending mechanisms via a form on your site, which gets the file from "your machine" to "your server". The PHP script which handles the upload can then use the FTP functions to transfer the file from "your website" to "other machine you ftp to".

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you have to use ftp to pull a file off your machine (as opposed to using a html form) your best bet would be to  set your local machine up as an ftp server. You would probably need an static ip address for this to be consistent. You could then have your script connect to your local machine and use ftp_get to grab test.txt.